# pulling not consistent data in firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a firebase project and decided to make some changes in the data structure. Now, I decided it would be better to add a placeholder image to the node below (Before, I used a dummy image to serve as a placeholder). Is there a way I can still get the dates below? and add the placeholder URL to another structure?

[image: Structure]

So what I would want is an array `dates = ["20180203","20180204","20180205"]` and then another array containing `placeholders = ["https.googleapis.whateverIsInTheDay80180203", "https.dummydefaultimage","https.dummydefaultimage"]`

```
    public func getAvailableDates(spotTitle:String, handler: @escaping (_ dateList:[String])->())
{
    var datesList:[String] = []
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"

    let allowedDays = 30

    ref.child("ImageLocationDates").child(spotTitle).observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
            for mydata in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
            {
                let date = mydata.key

                if date.count == 8 {

                    let testDate = formatter.date(from: date)
                    let cal = Calendar.current
                    let components = cal.dateComponents([.day], from: testDate!, to: cal.startOfDay(for: Date()))
                    let dateDistance = components.day! // integer of distance between today and date provided
                    if dateDistance < allowedDays {
                        if !datesList.contains(convertDate(stringDate: date)){
                            datesList.insert(convertDate(stringDate: date), at: 0)

                        }
                        else {
                            print("getting duplicate data")
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            handler(datesList)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: What do those data sets you want have to do with each other? It seems you want an array of placeholders and an array of timestamps? I don't see the problem!

Comment: Yes you are right about the Array.currently, I can only get the “key” which is the dates (or time stamps), how can I get the array of images that correspond to those dates?

Answer (score 0):

In **Firebase real time database** you can have a few ways to structure you data. Keep in mind you want your data not to get too deep. Usually my limit is 3 folds not more. To keep things shallow then, you can normalize and distribute your data which includes a bit of duplication sometimes but it can speed up queries and will decrease the amount of data users download each time.

Look at three structures below :

**(A)**

```
D_street: 
    2012491203 : 
        placeholder: "https://...."
    2012491203 : 
        placeholder: "https://...."
    ...
```

**(B)**

```
D_street_dates: 
    2012491203 : true
    2012491203 : 
    ...

D_street_placeholder:
    2012491203 : "https://...."
    2012491203 : "https://...."
    ...
```

**(C)**

```
D_street_dates: 
   id1 : 
       date: 2012491203 
       placeholder: "https://...."
   id2 : 
       date: 2012491203 
       placeholder: "https://...."
   ...
```

Each one of structures above can be great depending on your use case. in **A** you can query by the date (key) and once you get the results you have actually downloaded the placeholders too because they are the values.

In **B** you only download date when you query D_street_dates and then you have to do another query to get the placeholder per each date from D_street_placeholder.

In **C** you structure data per an ID or userID or something that both date and placeholders are properties of and whenever you query ids you get both dates and placeholder for that.